# Force software rendering in Adobe Reader 10.1.3

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry, adobe, adobe-reader

In Adobe Reader 10.x there is an option under Edit>Preferences...>3D & Multimedia to set the renderer to use the software renderer instead of Directx.  I've read that using the software setting will garner better performance. I'm looking for a way to set this via registry or gpo - domain wide.  Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The per-user value is stored under  `HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\3D` as a `REG_SZ` value named `t3DPreferredRenderer`.  Setting the data to `Software` will select the Software Renderer.

You can apply this setting using Group Policy Preference Client Side Extensions very easily.  Should you need a different method (ADM, ADMX) update your question with more information.

A simple script example as well:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\3D" /v "t3DPreferredRenderer" /t REG_SZ /d "Software" /f
```